# What are the electronics parts of a CD player

Tags: components

Can more experienced engineers give me their input on this. If I open a CD player, what electronic parts should I expect to find?

Comment: May I refer you to a type of DNA sequencing called *"shotgun sequencing"*. To characterize the DNA of certain organism, it is blasted into millions of pieces, then sequenced in parallel. I suggest the same with a CD player, using a big hammer and a room full of people. :D (I kid..)

Comment: The general process you are asking about is often called a _teardown_, which is used by engineers to examine a product. Searching for CD player teardown will find one at iFixit, that can give you a general idea even if you do not have the same model. http://www.ifixit.com/Teardown/Sony-CD-Walkman-D-NF430-Teardown/1249/2

Comment: @ tyblu, lol, this was my favourite thing when I was a kid. Electronics are just made to be smashed to smithereens

Answer (score 5):

By searching the web, you'll find plenty of information.

Here's a teardown of a CD player.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=gpi_8Vodi5w

Here's a picture of the internals:

[image]
<sub>(source: [howstuffworks.com](https://static.howstuffworks.com/gif/cd-parts.jpg))</sub>

Here's a basic guide to the workings http://electronics.howstuffworks.com/cd4.htm

But, the best way to find out is to take it apart.

Comment: and the lasers in these are IR, aren't they?

Comment: @JustJeff, yes IR, 780 nm